# HTM/CSS - Sticky footer not centered

Tags: html, css, position, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to center a sticky footer to no avail. This is what I tried:

HTML:

```
    <div class="footer-be">
        <div class="footer-be-middle">
            <eGov:EgovReusableContentControl runat="server" id="menuContent" ReusableContentListItemTitle="MasterPage_FooterMenus"/>
        </div>                              
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .footer-be {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
        background-color: white !important;
        font-family: "Calibri";
    }

    .footer-be-middle
    {   
        text-align: center;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 60%;
        margin: 0 auto;


    }
```

I am using SharePoint 2013 with a customized (in-house) theme. I had to modify the footer part (remove it) because I need the footer to be stickied to the bottom whenever the user scrolls.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Removing the margins is the only option in combinatie with the 100% width.

Comment: Besides what @Pangloss said: If `<eGov:EgovReusableContentControl>` gets replaced by SharePoint, what exactly is the resulting HTML-structure? Is it just text or maybe some other (block level) elements, which won't be centered by using `text-align: center;`?

Comment: The sharepoint control is just 3 divs with the middle div containing the text and the left and right containing an image http://i.imgur.com/nIePWP9.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, why does the footer have margin if it has 100% width?
so i'd get rid of the margins, so now you have a 100% wide element at the very bottom of the page.
Second, you will want to give the centered div an automatic horizontal margin.
html:

```
 <div class="footer-be">
   <div class="footer-be-middle">
     <eGov:EgovReusableContentControl runat="server" id="menuContent" ReusableContentListItemTitle="MasterPage_FooterMenus"/>
   </div>                              
</div>
```

css:

```
.footer-be {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: red !important;
    font-family: "Calibri";
}

.footer-be-middle
{   
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;

  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
}
```

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2zr7gr7z/

Comment: Unfortunately none of the mentioned solutions worked. The footer looks like the following (it is not centred correctly): http://i.imgur.com/nIePWP9.png. As you can see there is more space on the right

Comment: are you sure it's not because the content of .footer-be-middle isn't filling up the space you're giving it?
PD: this conversation is going to be so confusing...